# Visit each HTML element and apply inline CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, visitor-pattern

I need to apply some css styles to an `IMarkupElement`. The generated HTML is only for emails so all styles are inline styles and the selectors are very simple, just element names, ids or class names can be used. I'm not sure whether a `Visitor` is the right tool to apply styles to elements but it seemed to fit for the task.

This is the `IMarkupElment`:

```
public interface IMarkupElement : ICollection<object>, IFormattable
{
    string Name { get; }
    IDictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; }
    IMarkupElement Parent { get; set; }
    int Depth { get; }
}
```

The `StyleVisitor` works recursively and finds all `IMarkupElement` nodes and redirects the style creations to the `Element` method. Styles are provided via a `Dictionary<string, string>` where the key is a single selector like element name, #id or .class. I have another module that parses a very simple css file into such a dictionary.

```
public class StyleVisitor
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _styles;

    public StyleVisitor([NotNull] IDictionary<string, string> styles)
    {
        _styles = styles ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(styles));
    }

    public IMarkupElement Visit([NotNull] IMarkupElement element)
    {
        if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(element));

        var selectors = GetSelectors(element).Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        var style = Element(selectors);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(style))
        {
            element.Attributes.Remove("style");
        }
        else
        {
            element.Attributes["style"] = style;
        }

        foreach (var child in element)
        {
            if (child is IMarkupElement e)
            {
                Visit(e);
            }
        }

        return element;
    }

    // Gets element, id and class selectors.
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetSelectors(IMarkupElement element)
    {
        yield return element.Name;

        if (element.Attributes.TryGetValue("id", out var id))
        {
            yield return $"#{id}";
        }

        if (element.Attributes.TryGetValue("class", out var classes))
        {
            foreach (var className in Regex.Split(classes, @"\s+").Select(className => className.Trim()))
            {
                yield return $".{className}";
            }
        }
    }

    private string Element(IEnumerable<string> selectors)
    {
        var styles = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var selector in selectors)
        {
            if (_styles.TryGetValue(selector, out var style))
            {
                // Fix the ";" but trim it first in case there is already one to avoid an "if".
                styles
                    .Append(style.Trim().TrimEnd(';'))
                    .Append(";");
            }
        }
        return styles.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is the test that passes that I wrote for it so far:

```
[TestClass]
public class StyleVisitorTest
{
    private static readonly IMarkupElement Html = MarkupElement.Builder;

    [TestMethod]
    public void Visit_WithStyles_Applied()
    {
        var html = Html
            .Element("p", p => p
                .Append("foo ")
                .Element("span", span => span
                    .Attribute("class", "qux")
                    .Append("bar"))
                .Append(" baz"));

        Assert.AreEqual(@"<p>foo <span class=""qux"">bar</span> baz</p>", html.ToHtml());

        var styleVisitor = new StyleVisitor(new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
            [".qux"] = "font-family: sans-serif;"
        });

        html = styleVisitor.Visit(html);

        Assert.AreEqual(@"<p>foo <span class=""qux"" style=""font-family: sans-serif;"">bar</span> baz</p>", html.ToHtml());
    }
}
```

Before I write more complex html and tests I wanted to ask you what do you think about the `StyleVisitor`?

---

(Just for reference: this is build on top of an improved version of the [Functional Html builder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159043/functional-html-builder))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick review:

1. You shouldn't name classes/methods after patterns (except when pattern name makes sense semantically, like `factory`). `StyleVisitor.Visit` does not tell me anything, about what this class does. But, say, `CssManager.ApplyStyle` does.
2. Its hard to tell what `Element` method does at first glance. I mean it is called `Element` (add a verb?) but it returns `styles`? Weird.
3. `Visit_WithStyles_Applied` contains what looks like two separate tests. One tests your parser, another tests `StyleVisitor`. Separate them?

P.S. There is also quite a lot of `string`s in your code. Selector is a string, attribute is a string, style is a string, etc. Indeed all of them are technically strings but they all have different domain meaning. Maybe you should consider adding more classes to your domain model to represent those entities. You will gain the safety of strong types, but you will have to write more boilerplate code. So there is a trade off.

Comment: _You shouldn't name classes/methods after patterns_ This is what I usually say too ;-) this time however I was influenced by the `ExpressionVisitor` and this is the only explanation I have for this name (which is not a good one, indeed, so I really should change it). All are great points.

Comment: You will find that when writing DOM JavaScript without jQuery there are a *lot* of strings and everything is a string and you begin to feel rather [Stringly Typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any strong objections to your code and the other answer does a good job of addressing some slight naming issues. My problem is on a much larger scale - I think your domain model is far too simplistic.

Consider this CSS:

```
.i-should-be-applied-first {
    position: relative;
} 

#i-should-be-applied-second {
    position: static;
}
```

Now, look at your code: which rule will be in-lined first? Now, I haven't actually compiled your code, let alone run it, but I'm sure you'll apply the styles in the wrong order.

And another example:

```
.class-1 {
}

.class-2 {
}
```

With the html:

```
<p class="class-2 class-1"></p>
```

By modelling your stylesheet as a simple `IDictionary<string, string>` you lose the order of the rules. You have to know which rule came first to in-line the rules in the right order! That's why it's called a *cascading* style sheet.

It looks like you're only doing a simple thing so I think you can reasonably ignore specificity and media queries.

Build up the domain!

Comment: You are absolutely right and I hadn't thought of the order because as far as email css is concerned there aren't many options so the styles will be mostly a single class that will be inlined... however when I think of it now and if I would want to override a `background-color` then it would probably go wrong. I should definitely improve it.

Comment: @t3chb0t - I've recently been through this exact problem at work. After realising just how complex it was going to be, I ended up using [`Premailer.Net`](https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net)