# TagHelper for class inlining

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core

I'm building a RESTful service that [sends emails](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188294/mailermiddleware-for-sending-partialviews-via-email) with body rendered by partial views. It replaces my [old solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165812/visit-each-html-element-and-apply-inline-css) that used hardcoded templates of `IHtmlElement` inside each application.

One of its features is to inline `class`es as `style`. I'm using `class` because it's easier to design a view this way. Since it's about emails, I'm not expecting any fency style selectors and to make it simple I'm using only `class`es.

---

#### `InlineClassTagHelper`

The inlining is driven by the `InlineClassTagHelper`. It *stops* at each element with the `class` attribute and checks if there are classes prefixed with `m-` (it's my custom prefix that stands for *mail*). It then looks for a style in the parsed `.css` file. Its name is always `wwwroot/css/Conroller.Action.css`. When found, it sets the `style` attribute and removes the `class` one.

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "class")]
public class InlineClassTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly CssProvider _cssProvider;

    public InlineClassTagHelper(CssProvider cssProvider)
    {
        _cssProvider = cssProvider;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound, ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var classNames =
            output
                .Attributes["class"]
                ?.Value
                .ToString()
                .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (classNames is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var inlineableClassNames =
            (from className in classNames
             where className.StartsWith("m-")
             select SoftString.Create(className)).ToImmutableHashSet();

        if (inlineableClassNames.None())
        {
            return;
        }

        var cssFileName =
            $"wwwroot/css/" +
            $"{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]}." +
            $"{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]}.css";

        var css = await _cssProvider.GetCss(cssFileName);

        var declarations =
            from ruleset in css
            from selector in ruleset.Selectors
            join className in inlineableClassNames on selector equals className
            select ruleset.Declarations.TrimEnd(';');

        var style = declarations.Join("; ");

        if (style.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            // Make debugging of missing styles easier by highlighting the element with a red border.
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid #ff6666; border-radius: 3px;");
        }
        else
        {
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("style", style);
            output.Attributes.RemoveAll("class");
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### *Caching*

To avoid multiple loads (for each `class` attribute occurance) the `.css` file is *cached* for the lifetime of a request and loaded by another helper service I call `ICssProvider`.

```
public interface ICssProvider
{
    Task<Css> GetCss(string fileName);
}

public class CssProvider : ICssProvider
{
    private readonly IFileProvider _fileProvider;

    private Css _css;

    public CssProvider(IFileProvider fileProvider)
    {
        _fileProvider = fileProvider;
    }

    public async Task<Css> GetCss(string fileName)
    {
        if (_css is null)
        {
            var cssFile = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(fileName);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(cssFile.CreateReadStream()))
            {
                var cssString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                _css = CssParser.Default.Parse(cssString);
                Debug.WriteLine($"{fileName} loaded.");
            }
        }

        return _css;
    }
}
```

This is registered in `Startup` as

```
services.AddScoped<CssProvider>();
```

---

#### Example

When the tag-helper finds an element like this one:

> ```
> <h2 class="m-title">@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
> ```

it turns it into this:

> ```
> <h2 style="color: blueviolet;">About</h2>
> ```

where the `.css` is:

> ```
> m-title {
>     color: blueviolet;
> }
> ```

---

Would you say it's a good solution or do you see any room for improvement?

Comment: Initial observation, assuming `CssParser` is static *(tight coupling to static dependencies)*,  is there any way to abstract that out and have it explicitly injected via constructor?

Comment: @Nkosi you're right, it should be injected. I actually have an interface for it, it's the `ICssParser` and I am able to do it correctly, but I also have this `Default` property in case I'm too lazy for a full DI ;-)

Comment: The CSS provider can cache the filename mapped to the CSS in a dictionary. The current design uses the same one for all file names after the initial set.

Comment: You also need to register the interface. You are only registering the implementation.

Comment: @Nkosi I think this is ok because there is only one file per action and each action is one request, right? So for each request there will be only a single fine in the _cache_. That's what the `Scoped` service registration does. It is resolved one per request. And within a single request the tag-helper is created everytime it finds the `class` attribute but still this is the same request.

Comment: @Nkosi as far as the registration is concerned, it works. I don't know any other way. With `Autofac` you'd do `.As<ICssProvider>` indeed. But `asp.net-core` does not have such extension.

Comment: core has `services.AddScoped<ICssProvider, CssProvider>();`. Your original registers the implementation but not the abstraction. Classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial observation, assuming `CssParser` was static *(tight coupling to static dependencies)*, was to abstract that core functionality out into its own concern and have it explicitly injected via constructor.

That was done. However, the extracted helper service implementation was registered like

```
services.AddScoped<CssProvider>();
```

While it works, for a more SOLID design, classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions.

An abstraction exists, so I suggest refactoring the helper to explicitly depend on `ICssProvider` abstraction

```
//...code removed for brevity

private readonly ICssProvider _cssProvider;

public InlineClassTagHelper(ICssProvider cssProvider) {
    _cssProvider = cssProvider;
}

//...code removed for brevity
```

and register the abstraction with its implementation in the composition root 
 *(Startup)* with the following extension

```
services.AddScoped<ICssProvider, CssProvider>();
```

Comment: Oh, I don't know how I missed that it takes two generic parameters! :-o