# Notification system

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core, razor

I would like to implement a mail notification system

**Notification.cs**

```
public abstract class Notification
{
    private IEmailSender emailSender;

    public string To { get; }

    public virtual string Subject { get; }

    public virtual string Template { get; }

    public virtual object Model { get; }

    public Notification(IEmailSender emailSender, string to, object model)
    {
        this.emailSender = emailSender;
        this.To = to;
        this.Model = model;
    }

    public virtual async Task SendAsync()
    {
        var engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
            .UseFilesystemProject(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
              .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
              .Build();

        string message = await engine.CompileRenderAsync(this.Template, this.Model);

        await emailSender.SendEmailAsync(To, Subject, message);
    }
}
```

**RegisterConfirmationNotification.cs**

```
public class RegisterConfirmationNotification : Notification
{
    public RegisterConfirmationNotification(IEmailSender emailSender, string to, object model)
        : base(emailSender, to, model)
    {

    }

    public override string Subject => "Account Confirmation";

    public override string Template => "Views/EmailTemplates/RegisterConfirmation.cshtml";
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
var notification = new RegisterConfirmationNotification (emailSender, model.Email, new RegisterConfirmationViewModel { FirstName = "John" } );
await notification.SendAsync();
```

My problem is that I have the impression to mix a lot of things that should not be mixed. 
My class is responsible for compiling the `Razor` template but also sending the mail.

How could we separate things?

Comment: Is this an _ordinary_ program or maybe an asp.net-core web-service?

Comment: asp.net-core mvc with asp.net-core Identity 2.0

Comment: In case you are not aware of that... you don't need any external packages for that. All you need is to implement a custom middleware that intercepts the view returned as a response that you can send via email. Maybe my question that solves the same thing helps you [Middleware for sending PartialViews via email](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188294/middleware-for-sending-partialviews-via-email). Your controller would just return a `PartialView` instead of a full one, e.g. [`TestController.cs`](https://github.com/he-dev/Mailr/blob/master/Mailr/src/Controllers/TestController.cs)

Comment: The notification is sent in the `Register` method in `AccountController`. There are operations that are performed before and after in this method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already suspected, your code is trying to do too much. Consider separating functionality out into their own distinct concerns. (SRP/SoC -Single Responsibility Principle / Separation of Concerns)

Your abstract `Notification` acts more like a base model and should be refactor to reflect that

```
public abstract class Notification {

    public string To { get; }

    public abstract string Subject { get; }

    public abstract string Template { get; }

    public virtual object Model { get; }

    public Notification(string to, object model) {
        this.To = to;
        this.Model = model;
    }
}
```

The class is now responsible solely for storing the data to be sent.

This would mean that the `RegisterConfirmationNotification` class definition would now look like

```
public class RegisterConfirmationNotification : Notification {
    public RegisterConfirmationNotification(string to, object model)
        : base(to, model) {

    }

    public override string Subject => "Account Confirmation";

    public override string Template => "Views/EmailTemplates/RegisterConfirmation.cshtml";
}
```

`SendAsync` should be refactored into its own service abstraction and implementation and also follow explicit dependency principle by accepting a `Notification` argument directly

```
public interface INotificationService {
    Task SendAsync(Notification notification);
}
```

The implementation can be as simple as the following

```
public class NotoficationService : INotificationService {
    private readonly IEmailSender emailSender;

    public NotoficationService(IEmailSender emailSender) {
        this.emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(Notification notification) {
        var engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
           .UseFilesystemProject(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
             .Build();

        string message = await engine.CompileRenderAsync(notification.Template, notification.Model);

        await emailSender.SendEmailAsync(notification.To, notification.Subject, message);
    }
}
```

Even the compilation of the razor template can be extracted out into its own service in order for this code to be more SOLID. I'll leave that choice up to you to implement.

Finally, the `AccountController` would now explicitly depend on the `INotificationService` in order to be able to send notifications. The `Notification` derived model can be then passed to the service and the message sent.

```
public class AccountController : Controller {
    private readonly INotificationService notificationService;

    public AccountController(INotificationService notificationService) {
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
    }

    //...

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]MyModel model) {
        //...

        var notificationModel = new RegisterConfirmationViewModel { FirstName = "Jacques" };
        var notification = new RegisterConfirmationNotification (model.Email, notificationModel);
        await notificationService.SendAsync(notification);

        //...

        return View();
    }

}
```